# Android dispatchKeyEvent just get enter key event

Tags: android

I'm new in android and want to write simple detect key press in edit box ,for that purpose write this:

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(event.getKeyCode()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    };
```

but that code just get the enter key code,and dont get code for example a key ,what happen?How can i solve that problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "a key"?

Comment: @Mike keyboard button